# Resumable processor fault

Tags: c, processor, turbo-c

The code below is ok with `return n <= 100 && (printf("%d\n", n), print(n+1)) || 0;` but gives error for `return n <= 1000 && (printf("%d\n", n), print(n+1)) || 0;`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int print(int n)
{
   return n <= 1000 && (printf("%d\n", n), print(n+1)) || 0;
}

int main(void)
{
   print(1);
   return 0;
}
```

This code has following error :
Divide error expectation and
Resumable processor fault

I'm using Borland Turbo c++ 4.5 on windows 7.

How to fix it and also suggest a good C(specifically) IDE.
I think eclipse c/c++ is a good option but confused.

Comment: I'm looking for a c IDE which supports graphics.h , windows API , GTK+ etc to work on windows environment specifically.

Comment: [codeblocks](http://www.codeblocks.org) is also another great IDE.

Comment: Where does an IDE come into this? Is your question about the error with this code or is it about advice on choosing an IDE? I'd second the recommendation of codeblocks. Nice and simple, especially when set alongside Eclipse. On Windows there is always Visual Studio Express (free) but it forces you to use a very old dialect of C.

Comment: Interesting thing happens to me when I tried to run this code on visual c++ it gives output from 702 to 1000 what is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple stack overflow caused by the recursion depth. Your options:

1. Don't worry about it, you'd never write this sort of code for real.
2. Increase the stack size.
3. Do your homework assignment without using recursion if that is permitted.

Comment: "Increase the stack size" stack frame is portion occupied by a function on stack and stack is decided by operating system then what is the meaning of Increasing stack size.

Comment: Stack size is specified in the executable as one of the PE flags. Mind you, your compiler produces 16 bit output which is so astoundingly dated I personally have no idea what the default stack size is. My instincts are that with a more modern compiler you would not overflow the stack with that code. But if you increased the 1000 then you would. I'd be looking at option 3 and doing this in a for loop!